# Creating a drools route in Camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel, drools

I'm getting the following error while deploying a Camel route using the drools-camel component.

This is how my route looks like.

```
            <route id="drools-route">
                    <from uri="direct:drools-ep" />
                    <policy ref="droolsPolicy">
                            <unmarshal ref="xstream" />
                            <to uri="drools:node1/ksession1" />
                            <marshal ref="xstream" />
                    </policy>
            </route>

    <bean id="droolsPolicy" class="org.drools.camel.component.DroolsPolicy" />

268 [          http-bio-8080-exec-5] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.10-SNAPSHOT (CamelContext: camelctx) is starting
269 [          http-bio-8080-exec-5] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Tracing is enabled on CamelContext: camelctx
270 [          http-bio-8080-exec-5] ManagementStrategyFactory      INFO  JMX enabled.
271 [          http-bio-8080-exec-5] ultManagementLifecycleStrategy INFO  StatisticsLevel at All so enabling load performance statistics
272 [          http-bio-8080-exec-5] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Loaded 194 type converters
273 [          http-bio-8080-exec-5] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.10-SNAPSHOT (CamelContext: camelctx) is shutting down
274 [          http-bio-8080-exec-5] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.10-SNAPSHOT (CamelContext: camelctx) is shutdown in 0.004 seconds. Uptime 0.298 seconds.
275 [          http-bio-8080-exec-5] ContextLoader                  ERROR Context initialization failed
276 org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route drools-route at: >>> Policy[ref:droolsPolicy] <<< in route: Route[[From[direct:drools-ep]] -> [Policy[ref:droolsPolicy]    ]... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: drools://node1/ksession1 due to: Could not find GridNode for uri="node1/ksession1" in CamelContext. Check configuration.
277         at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1221)[camel-core-2.10-20120318.032230-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
278         at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:120)[camel-spring-2.10-20120318.032739-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
279         at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:243)[camel-spring-2.10-20120318.032739-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
280         at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)[spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
281         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)[spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
282         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)[spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
283         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)[spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
284         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)[spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
285         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)[spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
286         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)[spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
287         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
288         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
289         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
290         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
291         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
292         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
293         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
294         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
295         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1467)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
296         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.6.0_29]
297         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)[:1.6.0_29]
298         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_29]
299         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_29]
300         at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
301         at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)[:1.6.0_29]
302         at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)[:1.6.0_29]
303         at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
304         at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:673)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
305         at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:431)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
306         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)[servlet-api.jar:]
307         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)[servlet-api.jar:]
308         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
309         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
310         at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
311         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
312         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
313         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
314         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
315         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
316         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
317         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
318         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
319         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
320         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
321         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
322         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
323         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
324         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)[:1.6.0_29]
325         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)[:1.6.0_29]
326         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)[:1.6.0_29]
327 Mar 19, 2012 12:23:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a GridNode for uri="node1/ksession1" in your CamelContext...

Comment: No i don't have it. I'm going to add it now and try again. Do you know to add a GridNode in a Spring XML file ?

Comment: Try this link: http://planet.jboss.org/view/post.seam;jsessionid=63BEB774AB898FA442650144511E15EF?post=drools_server_drools_grid_for_remote_distributed_executions

Answer (score 0):

Example of Spring configuration:

```
<drools:grid-node id="node1" />

<drools:kbase id="AccountingKBase" node="node1">
    <drools:resources>
        <drools:resource type="DTABLE"
            source="classpath:rules/AccountingPeriods.xls" />
    </drools:resources>
</drools:kbase>
<drools:ksession id="AccountingKSession" name="AccountingKSession"
    type="stateless" kbase="AccountingKBase" node="node1" />

    <camel:route id="accountingRulesRoute">
        <camel:from uri="direct:accountingRulesRoute" />
        <camel:to uri="drools:node1/AccountingKSession" />
    </camel:route>
```